# how to quickly create many arrowheads on a path using illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

My question is simple. How to quickly create many arrowheads on a path using Adobe Illustrator? like this

[image]

Comment: make a pattern brush and draw two paths one for the arrows and one for the solid path.

Comment: Hi user15964, check out these threads as they are similar questions. [Distribute objects along a path in Illustrator](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5044/distribute-objects-along-a-path-in-illustrator) and [How to make a pattern follow a stroke, path or line?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21726/how-to-make-a-pattern-follow-a-stroke-path-or-line)

Comment: @AndrewH  why my path is lost after I use scatter bush or pattern bush？ see http://snag.gy/7yHF6.jpg

Comment: @user15964 Once you create your path (Before you use the pattern brush or scatter brush). I would select the path, copy, and ctrl + F to paste in front. You will have 2 lines. Apply the pattern or use scatter brush to the line in front. Maybe someone can comment on how to streamline this method if you can do this without making 2 paths.

Comment: You can assign 2 strokes to a single path in the appearances panel

Comment: @joojaa how to do it? more details?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest method I know is via a **Pattern Brush in Adobe Illustrator**.

Draw a path with a stroke and add an arrowhead:

[image]

Select the path and drag it to the **Brushes Panel**.

When Asked, tick the **Pattern Brush** option and then click `OK` *twice* to get out of the brush dialog.

[image]

You now have an arrowhead brush. If you wan the last segment to *not* have an arrowhead as in your sample.....

Remove the arrowhead from your original path:

[image]

Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and drag the path to the **Brush Panel** but **Hover over the last square for your existing brush**.

[image]

You'll see the square highlight, when you do let go.

Then click `OK` to get out of the brush dialog again. This will remove the arrowhead from the last brush segment.

[image]

Now, just draw a path, any path, and then with that path selected, click the brush you just created:

[image]

If you need arrowheads at sharp corners -- and you are using Illustrator CC or newer -- it's easy to configure corners. Double-click the brush in the **Brush Panel** to open the brush options window.

For the *corners* click the little box and choose `Auto-Between`. Do this for *both* the corner squares. This will allow the brush to appear correct at sharp corners.

[image]

[image]

(Note the corner options are only available in Illustrator CC+. Corners in older versions have to be manually configured and can be quite difficult at times so I'm not going into that.)

> These are overall basic steps to pattern brush creation in Adobe Illustrator and will work for many cases when you want a repeated element along a path. The [**HELP FILES**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-create-pattern-brush.html) for Illustrator may be useful if you are unfamiliar with pattern brushes.