# Adobe illustrator, arrowhead in the middle of a line

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm new to Illustrator, I was going to create some schematics with lines that have arrowhead in the middle, indicating the flow of liquid or gas.

I found the options to add arrowhead to either the start or the end of the line, but no option for the middle of the line.

I learned that an additional anchor point may help, but I don't know what to do next.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In addition to the link above, also see here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55976/drawing-a-line-segment-or-an-arc-with-an-arrow-head-placed-somewhere-between-t/55981#55981

Answer (score 1):

You need to [split the line](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/editing-paths.html#split_a_path) into two segments, so that each segment has its arrowhead. You can use the scissors tool for that.